# ngx-translate does not work properly even if i set translate.setDefaultLang('en')

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using `fa` and `en` languages for my app. There is two buttons that are supposed to change direction and language on click: `setDir(code)` function. After clicking buttons app is going to be reloaded. Language and direction change but ngx-translation does not work properly. It always shows the value of the fa.json file. Even if i set `translate.setDefaultLang('en')`.

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
export class MyApp {
  constructor(public platform: Platform, private storage: Storage,
translate: TranslateService, private modalController: ModalController,
statusBar: StatusBar) {
platform.ready().then(() => {
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splash = modalController.create(SplashPage);
  this.splash.present();
});
translate.setDefaultLang('en');
storage.get('languageCode').then((lang) => {
  platform.setLang(lang, true);
  translate.use(lang);
});
this.storage.get('myDir').then((dir) => {
  platform.setDir(dir, true);
});
  }
  async setDir(code) {
    if (code === "fa") {
      await this.storage.set('myDir', 'rtl');
      await this.storage.set('languageCode', 'fa');
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      await this.storage.set('myDir', 'ltr');
      await this.storage.set('languageCode', 'en');
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-item text-end color="none" menuClose="" id="lis-sell" class="mymenu">
{{'simple_sale' | translate}}
</ion-item>
```

**fa.json**

```
{
"simple_sale": "فروش"
}
```

**en.json**

```
{
"simple_sale": "sale"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
...
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
...
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
TranslateModule.forRoot({
loader: {
provide: TranslateLoader,
useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
deps: [HttpClient]
}
}),
...
```

Comment: Sorry your explanation of the problem is not clear enough. Try to restructure it: describe target user experience in detail first (user journey) then cover what is not working for you.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko tnx for response. i've managed to solve my problem with storage but still i cant work with ngx-translate. i edited the codes and explanation. hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow. i feel so stupid. everything works fine. its just i had defined two separate menu and i was using ngx-translate for the values in the menu. one menu is working in rtl. when app changes direction to ltr, the rtl menu will disable and ltr one become enable. so the problem was completely from my stupidity  that i've forgot i have two separate menu and i was just setting translate values for one.